# Change pitch of a wav file without changing the Sample rate?

Tags: pitch

I'm creating a Python library I call PAL, (Python Audio Library) and I need some help. What ways are there to change the pitch of a wav file without changing the sampling rate? I have complete access to the data contained in said file as numbers so if there is an equation or method that would work please let me know. To recap

- Change the pitch
- Don't touch the sampling rate
- I can mathematically change the samples freely

Comment: As I said in the question, this is with a `.wav` file.

Comment: Hello. Voting to migrate this question to dsp.stackexchange as it is related to signal processing and not to sound design.

Comment: Why can't there just be one stack exchange where all questions are allowed -.-

Comment: @CoderBoy Would you even want to *read* such a stack? It would be impossible to find anything about audio or DSP among the Mathematics and Interpersonal Skills questions! I can't even keep up with just the Mathematics stack. I have to filter it - it's just too much traffic.

Comment: @CoderBoy my god, that would be AWFUL.

Comment: @Todd I guess I see your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a library solution, there's a few, for instance [librubberband](https://github.com/lachs0r/rubberband), binaries available in many Linux distros.

If you need a wheel to reinvent, well, approaches may vary, from granular stretching (more applicable to time stretch, but these two effects always come hand in hand), to FFT uppitch (probably somewhat similar in the frequency domain), I doubt there's a standard consensus on how to implement this effect.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into those solutions. I am looking for a wheel to reinvent ;)